# How can I have two contracts in truffle test

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging

I'm using a contract to manage my contracts, and am not sure how to write a test.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't see how to get my `coolerDb` contract address.

This is my test.js

```
contract('CMC', function(accounts) {
  "use strict";

  it("check deployment", function(done) {
    let cmc = CMC.deployed();
    let coolerDb = CoolerDb.deployed();
    cmc.addContract("coolerDb", coolerDb).then(function(rc) {
      assert.equal(rc.c[0], true, 'Assert fail: not added');
    }).then(done).catch(done);
  });
});
```

The error is:

> Error: Contract address not set - deployed() relies on the contract class having a static 'address' value; please set that before using deployed().

Answer (score 1):

The address is shown when you run `truffle migrate`. The complete set of commands to [deploy](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/docs/getting_started/deploy/) the contract is:

```
# --compile-all recompiles all contracts.
# Omitting the flag compiles only those files that have been modified or added   
truffle compile --compile-all 
# Then deploy (here is where the address at which the contract is stored
# in the block chain is shown).
truffle migrate
```

Use that address in future contracts.

Comment: Hi Sebi, This is strange - I'm getting `Unknown command: migrate`. I'm running truffle v1.0.3

Comment: Upgrade to v2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Sebi gave the a great hint to look at the truffle command. The actual way that I got the contract was

1. made sure all the contracts were in truffle.js (and it was missing)
2. truffle deploy
3. read the address from the output

   Deployed: CoolerDb to address:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Luckily I didn't need to hard code the address because

```
let coolerDb = CoolerDb.deployed();
```

seems to get the address.